# imshow a gray image and a binary image python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, computer-vision

I have a grayscale image and a binary image, and I want to plot them side by side using hstack. It looks like there is kind of adjustment that been made yielding to darken the binary. Anybody faced this problem?

[image]

Here is my code

```
O = (self.img >= t) * 1
I = img
both = np.hstack((I, O))
imshow(both, cmap='gray')
show()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is to demonstrate a somewhat different from your case which I don't know of its data. I suspect that all the values in your array 'O' are zero, thus, the plot came out as a black pane.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))

# make up some data for demo purposes
raw = np.random.randint(10, size=(6,6))
# apply some logic operatioin to the data
O = (raw >= 5) * 1   # get either 0 or 1 in the array
I = np.random.randint(10, size=(6,6))  # get 0-9 in the array

# plot each image ...
# ... side by side
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)   # subplot one
plt.imshow(I, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)   # subplot two
# my data is OK to use gray colormap (0:black, 1:white)
plt.imshow(O, cmap=plt.cm.gray)  # use appropriate colormap here
plt.show()
```

The resulting image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code from the question works fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = plt.imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/oos05.png")[88:456,82:326]
t = 0.5

O = (img >= t) * 1
I = img
both = np.hstack((I, O))
plt.imshow(both, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The code neither worked for the questioner, nor for me. Please give an explanation how your code worked

Comment: @RahatZaman: This code works for me with Python 3.7.2 and the latest matplotlib. `img` is in the range [0,1], so `O` being 0s and 1s is correct.

Comment: @RahatZaman I think you have misunderstood my answer. I am showing a complete runnable code that works as it is. That is to say, the code from the question does work indeed; but of course it would depend on the input image.