# How to plot an image from a connection matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I want to write a script to create an image from a connection matrix. Basically, wherever there is a '1' in the matrix, I want that area to be shaded in the image. For eg -

[image]

I created this image using Photoshop. But I have a large dataset so I will have to automate the process. It would be really helpful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

**EDIT**

The image that I am getting after using the script is this. This is due to the fact that the matrix is large (19 x 19). Is there any way I can increase the visibility of this image so the black and white boxes appear more clear?

[image]

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615864/imshow-a-gray-image-and-a-binary-image-python)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest usage of `opencv` combined with `numpy` in this case.
Create two-dimensional `numpy.array` of `dtype='uint8'` with `0` for black and `255` for white. For example, to get 2x2 array with white left upper, white right lower, black left lower and black right upper, you could use code:

`myarray = numpy.array([[255,0],[0,255]],dtype='uint8')`

Then you could save that array as image with opencv2 in this way:

`cv2.imwrite('image.bmp',myarray)`

In which every cell of array is represented by single pixel, however if you want to upscale (so for example every cell is represented by 5x5 square) then you might use `numpy.kron` function, with following one line:

`myarray = numpy.kron(myarray, numpy.ones((5,5)))`

before writing image

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try this!

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm 
# Display matrix
plt.imshow(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100).reshape((10, 10)),cmap=cm.binary)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With a Seaborn heatmap:

```
import seaborn as sns
np.random.seed(3)
sns.set()
data = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(16,16), p=[3./4, 1./4])
ax = sns.heatmap(data, square=True, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, cbar=False, linewidths=.8, linecolor='lightgray', cmap='gray_r')
```

[image]

Note the reverse colormap `gray_r` to have black for 1's and white for 0's.