# Error in creating a numpy array from a text file

Tags: python, numpy, adjacency-matrix

I want to create a numpy array from a text file. However, I am getting the error " Wrong number of columns at line 10 ". The problem is probably in reading two-digit numbers in a column. I have even tried giving space between the columns but I am still getting the error.

[image: The text file]

How do I create a numpy array from this file?
It would be really helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: How many numbers are listed on line one? Now how many are on line 10? Seriously, count them. If you're trying to make a matrix, this file isn't going to work.

Comment: I want this to be an 19 x 19 array because of 19 rows and 19 columns.

Comment: @RamanDutt: Please count the number of enteries in the first row and the 10th and 11th row from the top. Then please post in the comment what are the counts. You will get your answer

Comment: There is a big difference between "117" and "1 17", between "016" and "0 16".

Comment: The count is the same i.e. 19. In line 10, the 117 should be interpreted as 11 and 7. 11 in column 9  and 7 in column 10.

Comment: You have to make your code smart enough to interpret 117 as 11 and 7. If you just read using space as a delimiter, that's not going to help. One can also see 117 as 1 and 17. You have to clearly specify/code so as to get what you want

Comment: Can you suggest a workaround? Which delimiter should I use?

Comment: Are you looking for a workaround using this existing format, with spaces?  If so, then it still begs the question of whether "117" for example is supposed to be interpreted as the numbers "11, 7", or "1, 17", or "1, 1, 7".  Is your data known to be strictly single digits?

Comment: I think it should be interpreted as 1 and 17

Comment: Ah, I understand what's gong on now.  I'll post an answer.

Comment: Please provide the input file as actual text - rather than a picture of text! Do you know what this is supposed to look like? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what's going on here. Your numbers are strictly on a "width" of 2 spaces.  You could use something like this to separate them:

```
>>> s = " 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9101112"
>>> print([ int(s[i:i+2].strip()) for i in range(0,len(s),2)])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

So read each line of your file into a string (in this example, "s"), and apply the same logic to split up the line in a list of integers.  Then you can create a lists of lists to convert into an Numpy array, or do other Numpy array work along the way.

Comment: I want to plot this array as an image. See question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845752/how-to-plot-an-image-from-a-connection-matrix.
Would I be able to do this by reading the file in a string as you suggested?

Comment: Now I am getting the error 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: I don't know if maybe it's different depending on your version of Python.  Try dropping the `.strip()`.

Comment: If you read the file in as a string, then break it up into a lists of integers, then I don't see why you couldn't plot it.